# How to specify "system:time_start" in time series charts in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to plot mean NDVI throughout the period of interest.

I have a polygon file loaded in Asset called `boundary`.

```
var start = ee.Date('2017-05-01'); //Dates of interest
var finish = ee.Date('2018-10-31'); 
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterBounds(boundary)
 .filterDate(start, finish)
 .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5)); 

var NDVI = sentinel.map(
    function(img) {
         return img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
                  .rename('NDVI');
    });

print(NDVI);
print(ui.Chart.image.series(NDVI, boundary, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10));
```

But it turns out `Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".` How do I specify "system:time_start" argument?

Comment: I suspect your `NDVI` collection might be empty with such a low cloud cover percentage. What is the output of the `print(NDVI)` statement?

Comment: You are right. I ran into `ImageCollection (Error) Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.` without `.filterBounds(boundary)`. After editing the code, `print(NDVI)` shows `ImageCollection COPERNICUS/S2 6 elements`

Comment: Just found `NDVI` doesn't have `system:time_start` but `system:index`.  Is there a way to specify this argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `copyProperties` method:

```js
var NDVI = sentinel.map(
    function(img) {
         return img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
                  .rename('NDVI')
                  .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
    });
```